# Logging in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, logging, exception

I'm currently working on a web application using Spring MVC, and I use the @ExceptionHandler annotation in every controllers of the application.

So basically I got a method like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public String handleException(RuntimeException ex) {
    injectedService.notifyAndLogException(ex.getMessage());
    return ("error_page");
}
```

My idea is to log and send an email to an application administrator in the injected service.
For now, I've tried to read some documentation about logging in spring application, and all the things I've seen is setting a static logger in each controller.

Like this:

```
 private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public String handleException(RuntimeException ex) {
    log.info("Logging error");
    injectedService.notifyException(ex.getMessage());
    return ("error_page");
}
```

I'd like to know what is the point to use a logger in each controller instead of using it in one point only (the service)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to know what is the point to use a logger in each controller instead of using it in one point only

If you use a single logger for the whole application, then every log message will be logged as coming from the same component. By using a logger per class or component, then your log files will contain information about *which* component logged the message.

For example, when you do:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);
```

This creates a logger with the name of the `Controller` class, which will generally be displayed in the log file, e.g.

```
2012-03-07:12:59:00 com.x.y.Controller Hello!
```

This is just a convention, but it's a good one that I advise you follow.

Answer (score 1):

a logger in each of your class files enables you get 'debug' or 'info' level when you are in production, or not able to connect a debugger.

Since you can limit via package or even class file name, what is logged, you can pin point to find errors, or to see what is happening under different load situations (concurrency problems, resources used ). If you use one generic logger, then you may flood your log file.

With the logger in the class that received the exception, you may be able to get at class variables that are not being passed into your exception handler.

I would also recommend that you do not do

```
injectedService.notifyAndLogException(ex.getMessage());
```

but pass the exception into your notify.  While stack traces can be notorious verbose, the messages usually are not very help full ( NullPointerException without a stacktrace ? ). In your notify service you can set the subject to ex.getMessage() and the body have the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers can extend an abstract class that declares a logger like that

```
 protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( getClass() );
```

This logger can be used in all controller and it will prefix the log message with the controller class name.

Comment: You can, yes, but this sort of inheritance-for-convenience is an anti-pattern, and is to be strongly discouraged.